# Problem with layout in detailViewController inside UISplitViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller

I am trying *UISplitViewController* in my app for the first time. I am doing everything programmatically so I don't use storyboards.
At start in *SceneDelegate* I create my splitViewController with master and detail controllers.

```
let detailVC = DetailsTableVC()
let masterVC = masterVC()
masterVC.delegate = detailVC

// Split view controller
let splitViewController = UISplitViewController()
splitViewController.viewControllers = [UINavigationController(rootViewController: masterVC), UINavigationController(rootViewController: detailVC)]
splitViewController.preferredDisplayMode = .allVisible
splitViewController.delegate = masterVC
```

Detail view class is UITableViewController, and I have 2 types of cells.
Everything works fine and I update my detailItem via delegate. When I rotate screen on iPhone 8 plus or any other iPhone with landscape it gives me this error. (It only happens once, for example if rotate device few times an error will appear only once)

> [TableView] Warning once only: UITableView was told to layout its
>   visible cells and other contents without being in the view hierarchy
>   (the table view or one of its superviews has not been added to a
>   window). This may cause bugs by forcing views inside the table view to
>   load and perform layout without accurate information (e.g. table view
>   bounds, trait collection, layout margins, safe area insets, etc), and
>   will also cause unnecessary performance overhead due to extra layout
>   passes. Make a symbolic breakpoint at
>   UITableViewAlertForLayoutOutsideViewHierarchy to catch this in the
>   debugger and see what caused this to occur, so you can avoid this
>   action altogether if possible, or defer it until the table view has
>   been added to a window. Table view: ; animations = {
>   position=;
>   bounds.origin=;
>   bounds.size=;
>   bounds.origin-2=;
>   bounds.size-2=; }; layer = ; contentOffset: {0, -64}; contentSize:
>   {93.666666666666657, 124.49999999999999}; adjustedContentInset: {64,
>   0, 0, 0}; dataSource: DetailsTableVC: 0x105612130>>

Am I doing everything right? How can I remove this error?